# Concatenating string in Text or Label property

Tags: asp.net

How would you concatenate a string from a resource assembly to an asterisk(*) in the Text property in an asp:Label control?

For example:

```
<asp:Label ID="someLabel" ... 
   Text="<%$ ExternalAssembly|FileName, resourceName %>*" runat="server".../>
```

End result is to display 'Name*'

Thanks

Comment: are you trying to show a required field ?

Comment: Why not like this: `<asp:Label ...><%$ ExternalAssembly|FileName, resourceName + "*" %></asp:Label>`

Comment: No, in some cases I want to append a colon(:), asterisk(*) or any other character that doesn't need translation to whatever is in the external assembly, eg: Surname:, Name* etc

Comment: @MelanciaUK: have tried that, gives concatenation errors

Comment: What about that: `<asp:Label ...><%$ ((string)(ExternalAssembly|FileName, resourceName)) + "*" %></asp:Label>`

Answer (score 1):

## Reference a server-side function to return the desired string.

*I apolgize, but this will be in vb.net. However, it is minimal code so I don't think it will be too hard to translate into C# if that's what you need.*

**Steps**

1. Create the ASP.NET tag for the label control.
2. Inside the text attribute, insert a data-binding expression for the function `getAssembly()` . Example: `Text='<%# getAssembly("Fullname")%>'` We will build this function in a moment. **Also note** that it accepts a parameter to identify what piece of information you need regarding the assembly. **Another common mistake** is not using single quotes for the inline expression (because double quotes will conflict with the string parameter).
3. Import the necessary namespaces `System` and `System.Reflection` into the code-behind.
4. Create the function `getAssembly(ByVal InfoItem as String)` in the code-behind (details for this function are below).
5. Add a line in the `Sub Page_Load()` to bind data to the assemblyLabel control when the page is loaded.

Here is the necessary code in detail for each step:

---

**ASP.NET Tag**

```
<asp:Label ID="assemblyLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# getAssembly("Fullname")%>'></asp:Label>
```

**Function in the Code-Behind**

```
Public Function getAssembly(ByVal InfoItem As String) As String

Dim a As AssemblyName = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly.GetName()

Select Case InfoItem
    Case "Name"
        Return a.Name
    Case "Fullname"
        Return a.FullName
    Case "Version"
        Return a.Version.ToString
    Case Else
        Return ""
    End Select

End Function
```

**Necessary imports:**

```
Imports System
Imports System.Reflection
```

**Bind the data in Page_Load:**

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

assemblyLabel.DataBind()

End Sub
```

---

### The entire code-behind...

```
Imports System
Imports System.Reflection
Public Class WebForm1
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        assemblyLabel.DataBind()

    End Sub

    Public Function getAssembly(ByVal InfoItem As String) As String

        Dim a As AssemblyName = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly.GetName()

        Select Case InfoItem
            Case "Name"
                Return a.Name
            Case "Fullname"
                Return a.FullName
            Case "Version"
                Return a.Version.ToString
            Case Else
                Return ""
        End Select

    End Function


End Class
```